# Does having multiple Windows 7 logins compromise overall performance?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I'm considering to make a Win7 login for every environment - work, college, etc - for the sake of organization and concentration. I'm not sure if having many of them, probably 4-5, will compromise the performance of my laptop in any way, though. Should I be concerned about it?

Does having multiple Windows 7 logins compromise overall performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Unless you plan on using Fast User Switching and keeping several of the accounts logged in at one time, which would eat into memory and potentially CPU time if there were apps open in the other accounts.